# Error with VC++ 2005 with winsock2

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winsock, platform-sdk

```
#include <winsock2.h>
```

This Error appers only in VC++ 2005. There is no error in 2008.

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install platform SDK first. Please install the Windows 7 SDK using [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx).

When you are ready, open VC++ 2005, select the Options from the Tools menu, then VC++ Directories. From "Show directories for:" list you need to select "Include files". Please double click on the next item after the last one on the list and select following directory:

`{SDK}\Windows\v7.1\Include`

where `{SDK}` is your SDK installation directory. Close the window and compile again.

[image: VC++ Options window]

Answer (score 0):

Check your VC++ 2005 installation to see if winsock2.h is installed.  If you are using a free edition, it may not be.  You may have to install a pro edition, or download a newer Platform SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I won't agree this would an error on any of VS versions/editions. It seems to be problem with Include Directory setting. Check it in Tools -> Options, Projects and Soltions -> VC++ Directories, and there lookup under `Include Files`.